# How to execute function on link click in dataview in ExtJS

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have the following code:

```
xtype: 'dataview',
//title: 'test',
preventHeader: true,
height: 100,
bodyPadding: 10,
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<a href="#">{name}</a>',
    '</tpl>'
),
store: new RateManagement.store.ServiceStore(),
itemclick: function(this, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
    console.log(this);
}
```

I am trying to output the selected link's text to the console; however, I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token this

Here is a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/1/

How can I run code when the user clicks a link in the data view?

Ref. http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.view.View-event-itemclick

**Edit:** This is my actual code (slightly different from the jsfiddle).

```
xtype: 'dataview',
itemSelector: 'a.serviceLink',
tpl: tpl2,
store: new RateManagement.store.ServiceStore(),
listeners:{
    "itemclick": function(dataview, record) {
        console.log(dataview);
    }
}
```

And, the `tpl2` variable is defined as:

```
var tpl2 = new Ext.XTemplate(
    '<tpl for=".">',
    '<a href="#">{name}</a>',
    '</tpl>'
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matt is correct, you can't use 'this' in the function like that. You also need to add it as a listener, as I have done here: http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/2/

```
listeners:{
  "itemclick": function(dataview, record) {
    console.log(dataview);
  }
}
```

This at least logs something to the console.

## UPDATE

If you are specifying the 'itemSelector' config option, you need to make sure this is reflected in your 'tpl' config option. For example if itemSelector is 'a.serviceLink', your tpl needs to be something like:

```
new Ext.XTemplate(
  '<tpl for=".">',
  '<a href="#" class="serviceLink">{name}</a>',
  '</tpl>'
)
```

Please see here for a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/4/

Comment: I see it works in the fiddle, but my code is slightly different from that example.  I am using an `itemSelector`.  For some reason, I am not getting anything logged to the console, and I am not getting any errors.  I updated the question with my actual code.

Comment: Well the itemSelector component doesn't seem to have an "itemclick" event, so that's probably why it doesn't work! See the documentation here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector I have no experience working with this component, so I'm not sure what the solution is. Have you got a JSFiddle of that?

Comment: Yes, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/k4ggq/3/.  There are no errors in the console.  I have tried just using the code of your fiddle, but ExtJS complains and says, "you must specify both `itemSelector` and and `tpl`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  I completely forgot about that!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `this` as a variable name in your function, change it to `dataview` or something:

```
itemclick: function(dataview, record, item, index, e, eOpts) {
    console.log(this);
}
```

Comment: There are no errors but nothing is logged to the console.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, you need to add it to the `listeners` config.

Answer (score 1):

```
xtype: 'dataview',
preventHeader: true,
height: 100,
bodyPadding: 10,
autoEl:{
    tag: 'a',
    href: '',
    onClick: 'nameYouFunction'
}
```